# ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between not following Half-Open approach

Tags: java, java-time

I have 2 `LocalDate` that I want to find difference between:

```
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of(2018,11,30);
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2019, 5, 1);
```

When I execute:

```
long mthsDiff = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(date1, date2);
```

This returns 5, but it really should be 6.

Why is `ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between` not respecting `Half-Open approach`? Shouldn't it return month of April (`2019-04-30`)?
Am I missing something?

I understand that second argument is exclusive.
Below are scenarios I expect:

```
date1 = 2018-11-16
date2 = 2019-04-15
expect 5

date1 = 2018-11-16
date2 = 2019-04-16
expect 5

date1 = 2018-11-16
date2 = 2019-04-17
expect 6

date1 = 2018-11-16
date2 = 2019-04-15
expect 5
```

Comment: Would you mind accept an answer or ask for details in comment ? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) says it all here:

> The calculation returns a whole number, representing the number of
>   **complete units** between the two temporals. For example, the amount in
>   hours between the times 11:30 and 13:29 will only be one hour as it is
>   one minute short of two hours.

The number of whole months between 30th of November and the 1st of May is 5:

1. December
2. January
3. February
4. March
5. April

Why do you think it should be 6? Half-open just says that the first day is inclusive and the last day is exclusive. Excluding the 1st of May does nothing, all of April is still in the range. Including the 30th of November is still not a whole month, so it's still 5.

Answer (score 2):

As the doc says about [`ChronoUnit.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-)

> The calculation returns a whole number, representing the number of complete units between the two temporals.

And

```
// these two lines are equivalent
between = thisUnit.between(start, end);
between = start.until(end, thisUnit);
```

---

So there is 5 complete month between

```
"2018-11-30"
December -> 1
January  -> 2
February -> 3
March    -> 4
May      -> 5
"2019-05-01"
```